# Wierd java string compare operation

Tags: java, string, compare

I am facing a weird java string comparison issue.

```
{

String a,b;
a = "http://www.abc.com/audiofiles/1349866054121.caf";
b = "http://www.abc.com/audiofiles/";

boolean flag = a.contains(b); // This should be true...

}
```

But unfortunatly it returns false. I have tried toLowerCase(), and trim() but no help..

Anyone knows the issue

Comment: no luck in my case...:S

working on android in eclipse

Comment: invisible chars in your file ?

Comment: i'd hate to disapoint you but for me it just returns true.

Comment: What about debugging `String.contains()`?

Comment: How about `String#startsWith(...)`

Comment: nops.. pasted both strings in notepad, no invisible characters..

its funny..:D

Comment: where do these strings come from? hardcoded or read from somewhere? because for me it returns `true` as well.

Comment: one from sqlite db and one from static variable...

Comment: To summarize: Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: There seems to be some encoding issue, or some other changes you might have done before comparing.. You need to show the code exactly where you are using it...

Comment: `static variable` worries me the most here...

Comment: OMG.. haha
sorry guys.. That was my mistake..m damn dumb..:X
Got it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `toCharArray()` on both strings and look at the characters one by one. That will answer your question. Output them as ints to make it easier to tell where they differ.